# Airflow dag tasks get stuck in running or no status

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I created a dag that has inside few subdags which run simple bash commands. I can see that almost from the beginning many of the tasks get stuck in the running or no status modes and don't move on. After some time i can see that more and more dag instances gets stuck and I'm left with only one instance really running.
What can I do to make sure this doesn't happen?

Here is my dag:

```
 from airflow import DAG
 from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
 from airflow.operators.subdag_operator import SubDagOperator
 from datetime import datetime, timedelta

default_args = {
'owner': 'airflow',
'depends_on_past': False,
'start_date': datetime(2016, 1, 1),
'email': ['airflow@airflow.com'],
'email_on_failure': False,
'email_on_retry': False,
'retries': 1,
'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
# 'queue': 'bash_queue',
# 'pool': 'backfill',
# 'priority_weight': 10,
# 'end_date': datetime(2016, 1, 1),
}

dag = DAG('performance', default_args=default_args, 
schedule_interval='@hourly', max_active_runs=30)

adapterSubDag = DAG('performance.adapterSubDagOperator',         
default_args=default_args)
for index in range(10):
  bash = BashOperator(
    task_id='bash_{}'.format(index),
    bash_command='java -jar /home/presidio/dev-projects/presidio-
core/presidio-workflows/tests/resources/jars/test.jar',
    dag=adapterSubDag)

adapterSubdagOperator = SubDagOperator(
 subdag=adapterSubDag,
 task_id='adapterSubDagOperator',
 dag=dag
)

presidioSubDag = DAG('performance.presidioSubDagOperator', 
default_args=default_args)
presidioSubdagOperator = SubDagOperator(
 subdag=presidioSubDag,
 task_id='presidioSubDagOperator',
 dag=dag
)

inputSubDag = DAG('performance.presidioSubDagOperator.inputSubDagOperator', 
default_args=default_args)
for index in range(10):
bash = BashOperator(
    task_id='bash_{}'.format(index),
    bash_command='java -jar /home/presidio/dev-projects/presidio-
core/presidio-workflows/tests/resources/jars/test.jar',
    dag=inputSubDag)

inputSubdagOperator = SubDagOperator(
 subdag=inputSubDag,
 task_id='inputSubDagOperator',
 dag=presidioSubDag
)


adeSubDag = DAG('performance.presidioSubDagOperator.adeSubDagOperator', 
default_args=default_args)
for index in range(10):
 bash = BashOperator(
     task_id='bash_{}'.format(index),
     bash_command='java -jar /home/presidio/dev-projects/presidio-
core/presidio-workflows/tests/resources/jars/test.jar',
    dag=adeSubDag)

adeSubdagOperator = SubDagOperator(
 subdag=adeSubDag,
 task_id='adeSubDagOperator',
 dag=presidioSubDag
 )

outputSubDag = 
DAG('performance.presidioSubDagOperator.outputSubDagOperator', 
default_args=default_args)
for index in range(10):
 bash = BashOperator(
    task_id='bash_{}'.format(index),
    bash_command='java -jar /home/presidio/dev-projects/presidio-core/presidio-workflows/tests/resources/jars/test.jar',
    dag=outputSubDag)

outputSubdagOperator = SubDagOperator(
 subdag=outputSubDag,
 task_id='outputSubDagOperator',
 dag=presidioSubDag
)

inputSubdagOperator >> adeSubdagOperator >> outputSubdagOperator
adapterSubdagOperator >> presidioSubdagOperator
```

Comment: Is it throwing any error ?  
sometimes you might receive error: This fails with Jinja template not found, if such error '{{"java -jar /home/presidio/dev-projects/presidio-core/presidio-workflows/tests/resources/jars/test.jar"}}' may work.

Comment: Facing same issue. Alex .. Did u get the resolution for this ?

Comment: Was this a new DAG or one that you'd previously worked on and changed? I only ask because I had a similar problem with a modified DAG that when updated in production was stuck in a `no status` state despite working fine in dev. We resolved it by deleted the DAG in production and recreating it with the new changes and it seemed to do the trick.